# How to track webview content with Google Analytics in android?

Tags: android, webview, google-analytics

I have a webview in my app and set its content like the following:

```
mWebView.loadUrl("http://.......");
```

I get my Google Analytics Tracker like the following:

```
public synchronized Tracker getTracker(TrackerName trackerId) {
        if (!mTrackers.containsKey(trackerId)) {

            GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
            Tracker t = (trackerId == TrackerName.APP_TRACKER) ? analytics
                    .newTracker(R.xml.app_tracker)
                    : (trackerId == TrackerName.GLOBAL_TRACKER) ? analytics
                            .newTracker(PROPERTY_ID) : analytics
                            .newTracker(R.xml.ecommerce_tracker);
            mTrackers.put(trackerId, t);

        }
        return mTrackers.get(trackerId);
}
```

My question is, How can i use this tracker to track the urls loaded in my webview?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just extend onPageFinished method

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

    // String url is what you are looking for
    // Do the analytics stuff here

    }
});
```